# How to choose a good test statistic to use in R

Tags: r, distributions, self-study, hypothesis-testing

I find it hard to understand how to use statistical tests in R.
I must use the most compatible statistical test to test if there is a significant difference between the means of 2 samples. I have 2 exercises:

1.

```
a<-rexp(32,1/3)
b<-rnorm(33,4)
```

2.

```
c<-rnorm(7,1,1)
d<-rnorm(9,2,3)
```

I can use a normal test, t-test (pooled, welbech, or the simple t_student), man_whitney, bootstrap, or permutation test.

For the 2 exercises, I don't know which test to use, and how to prove by R code why I used it. I read a lot of articles but i don't understand yet.
can someone help me please ?

Comment: Hi. This is really a statistics question, not a programming one, and there is a Statistics SE to ask such questions on.  I will give you a hint: the student t-test assumes that both distributions are normal, and have approximately equal standard deviations. Otherwise, the results are not meaningful.

Comment: @Spencer thanks for your help! can you give me the link  to Statistics SE please ? i don't find it, i would ask my question there

Comment: Thanks, @Bruno. I lost track of the Q when I went to copy the link.

Comment: This isn't answering your question but you really should store things as `c` in `R` because this is used to create vectors. Eg ` x <- c(1,2,3)`

Comment: Can you provide link or reference for Welbech statistical test?

Answer (score 2):

In (2), I suppose you are asked to test $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ against
$H_0: \mu_1 \ne \mu_2.$  Data are $n_1 = 7$ observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_1 = 1, \sigma_1=1)$ and $n_2 = 9$ observations from 
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_2 = 2, \sigma_2=3).$ A Welch (is that what you mean by 'Welbech'?) 2-sample t test is appropriate because it does not assume the two populations have the same variance (or standard deviation).

Results will be different for each run because you need to take (by simulation) samples of appropriate sizes from the two populations.
In R, with two data vectors `c` and `d`, the default two-sample t test
is the Welch test. (If you use parameter `var.eq=T` then the procedure becomes a pooled t test, which assumes equal variances.) For this run
(repeatable if you use the same seed), the two sample means are not
significantly different at the 5% level because the P-value is 
$0.0809 > 0.05.$ So you cannot reject $H_0$ (even though the two small samples are simulated with $H_0$ not true).

```
set.seed(607)
c<-rnorm(7,1,1)
d<-rnorm(9,2,3)
t.test(c,d)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  c and d
t = -1.9284, df = 10.643, p-value = 0.0809
alternative hypothesis: 
    true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.4614659  0.3036514
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.6670837 2.7459910
```

Overall, the power of the Welch test (probability of rejecting $H_0$ when it is false) can be found by looking at a large number of runs and noting
the percentage of runs with P-values $\leq 0.05.$ Sample sizes are so small
and distributions so nearly alike that you would be able to detect
that the population means differ in only 13% or 14% of actual tests of
this kind.

```
set.seed(2020)
p.val = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(7,1,1),rnorm(9,2,3))$p.val)
mean(p.val <= .05)
[1] 0.13864
```

(1) I am puzzled by the first problem. You are comparing means from two different families. Here are the difficulties:

- Technically, t tests require normal data for both samples, but often you can get useful results from them for nonnormal data, when sample sizes are large and neither sample is skewed or has far outliers. The exponential distribution is severely skewed and samples from it will often show skewness and far outliers.
- Mann-Whitney and permutation tests are best when the two populations are of the same shape (including same variance).
- Some authors suffer under the delusion (grossly mistaken) that for 'magic' samples of sizes $n \ge 30$ a pooled t test can be used for almost anything.

However, a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (not on your list) would be appropriate to see whether the two distributions are different. Certainly exponential and normal distributions *are* of different shapes. Also, they have different population means $3$ and $4,$ respectively.

```
set.seed(1776)
a<-rexp(32,1/3)
b<-rnorm(33,4)
ks.test(a,b)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  a and b
D = 0.47064, p-value = 0.001027
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The $D$ statistic is the maximum vertical distance between the empirical cumulative distribution functions (ECDFs) of the two samples (here plotted in orange for sample `a` and in blue for `b`).

```
plot(ecdf(a), col="orange")
  lines(ecdf(b), col="blue")
```

[image]

Even though the K-S test is not generally known for having good power, the sample sizes in (1) are large enough and distributions are different enough that this test rejected $H_0$ at the 5% level for almost all of the $100,000$ simulated samples `a` and `b` in the run below.

```
set.seed(4321)
p.val = replicate(10^5, ks.test(rexp(32,1/3),rnorm(33,4))$p.val)
mean(p.val <= .05)
[1] 0.99229
```

Even though not really appropriate both the pooled and the Welch two-sample t tests find a difference
in means at the 7% level and a Wilcoxon rank sum test finds a difference
in location at the 3% level. (Datasets `a` and `b` generated starting with
different seeds may give varying results.)

```
t.test(a,b, var.eq=T)$p.val  # pooled 2-sample t test
[1] 0.06026259
t.test(a,b)$p.value          # Welch 2-sample t test
[1] 0.06546807
wilcox.test(a,b)$p.value
[1] 0.02371882
```

More broadly, the pooled 2-sample t test does find a difference at the 5%
level in almost half of 100,000 runs (each with freshly simulated data). In my view, that hardly makes it an appropriate test, but the author of your book may be one of those 'magic 30' people.

```
set.seed(123)
p.val = replicate(10^5, t.test(rexp(32,1/3),rnorm(33,4), var.eq=T)$p.val)
mean(p.val <= .05)
[1] 0.48184
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your very good answer! But for (2), you use Welch test. But why is z-test not better than Welch test ? i learned that when you have the mean and variance of population, you need to use z-test, and when you don't have the variance, you need to use t-test

Comment: Your question emphasized looking for difference in means, so clearly means are unknown. You didn't say anything about knowing variances, so I assumed they're unknown. You're right about being able to use z test if means unknown and variances known. (But z test is not on your list of tests.) // Please clarify about whether Welch is on your list.

Comment: you're right 'I forgot to specify that we could use the z-test. And you're right i am looking for difference in means .For welbech, I actually meant the Welch test. And as regards standard deviations (or variance), they are given in the code: for rnorm (7,1,1), mean = 1 and variance = 1, and for rnorm (9,2,3), mean = 2 and variance = 3. After having clarified these points, what would be the most compatible test?
and for (1), I can't use the test you offered me unfortunately, if you could tell me which test is the most suitable it would help me a lot please. Alone i did not find yet

Comment: I understand. For the permutation tests you can use all the permutation tests, and bootstrap also. But the question I am asking myself is this: when we have samples normally distributed with their means and their known variance, I learned that we must use z-test (because the variance is known). On the other hand the 2 samples are small, and in this case I learned that it is necessary to use the t-test (in our case particularly the welch test). So, I would like to know how to choose the right test (between t-test and z-test) in this situation? (each has its advantages and disadvantages)

Comment: In my view for (1), _there is no correct choice among pooled t, Welch t, and z tests._ There are no grounds for a z test; if you say the variance of the exponential sample is known, then you have to say its mean is known. A sample size of 33 is not large enough for the mean of an exponential sample to be nearly normal. Nevertheless, my most recent simulation (at end of Answ) shows that pooled t does have almost 50% power to distinguish. But that has to be viewed against almost 100% power for K-S.